# Edit a scroll viewer in the design view of visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, scrollviewer

I have an input form that I want to edit in visual studios design view.  The form is placed within a scroll viewer but since the form is so long I can figure out how to actually scroll the scroll viewer so I can edit further down in the form since the design window is only showing what fits in the window size.  Is it possible to edit the entirety of the scroll viewer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either put the form into a `UserControl` and edit it there without scrollbars or you can increase the size of the `Window` at design time but leave it at its normal size at run-time.  You can achieve the latter effect by adding this to your XAML file:

```
<Window ...
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    ...
    d:DesignHeight="1000" d:DesignWidth="1000">
```